# losing original variable reference on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Newbie :)

I am trying to create a picture w/ description portfolio. It works fine on the first click of thumbnail for description, but the second click, the description is nowhere to be found on the page. Its almost like it uses the description once then, throws it away. How do I ensure this doesn't happen? To put description back in its original place in the html, or some other way? Trying to keep this simple but keeps getting more complicated. This is why designers outsource lol.

testpage:http://www.tsmillie.com/portfolio2.html

code:

```
$(".gallery a:has(img)").click(function() {

    var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
    var image = $(".photo_large");
        image.fadeOut('500', function () {
        image.attr({ src: largePath }) ;
        image.fadeIn('500');
                      });
    var description = $(this).next(".description").css("display", "inline");
    $(".caption").html(description);
      return false;
          });
```

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do? The testpage works like a charm to me

Comment: thanks :) but if you click a thumbnail image twice, the description disappears and is gone from the html completely.

Comment: click "websites" on the second slide to see the thumbnails. its a toggle that displays the thumbnails, then click a thumbnail 2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to this:

```
$(".gallery a:has(img)").click(function() {
    var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
    var image = $(".photo_large");
    image.fadeOut('500', function () {
        image.attr({ src: largePath }) ;
        image.fadeIn('500');
    });
    var description = $(this).next(".description");
    $(".caption").html(description.clone().css("display", "inline")); // <---- Changed
    return false;
});
```

I think it was moving the description into the caption rather than copying the html which is what I guess you want to do?

It now clones the content and displays that in the caption.

Comment: OK, that works, but now the "style hidden" is overridden next to the thumbnail. refresh page is live (ghosted)

Comment: so, I guess, I want to have the css display inline only applied when its in the caption.

Comment: @Theresa - I've updated it to use clone instead of html now. If you could try the latest update (I checked by updating the js in chrome on your site and it worked so it should be fine)

Comment: OMG, Mr. Infernal Badger, I greatly appreciate your help!!! Thank you! Wish I knew this language a lil' better. I'm teachin myself.

Comment: np, feel free to flag this as the correct answer if you want ;)

Comment: @Theresa I think there should be a tick under the arrows to the left of my answer. If you click that it marks it as the accepted answer. (I'm not entirely sure though as I've never asked a question)

Answer (score 0):

As InfernalBadger says, you're adding the reference to your `description` element to your `.caption` element, and when you replace the contents of `.caption`, you remove the previous description from the DOM